# How to make the Documents in the fire store display in an Array Adapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app that can insert data's in the Firestore. Each data has different Document names, How to get the Document names to be inserted in an Array Adapter? Can you give me some examples? This is the picture of my simple Array Adapter code and my Fire Store.
[image: This is my Fire Store]

[image: This is my simple Array Adapter]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: yo @AlexMamo About the Question I ask you in the pass I already find the answer so I decided that I Will not post another question about it. Can you help me about this?

Comment: Ok I will a picture.

Comment: What have you tried so far in code? I still cannot see your database structure.

Comment: I just edited my question just now and I still searcher ideas/examples in google.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to display the place names in a ListView using an ArrayAdapter would be to create a reference to "Marker PLaces":

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference placesRef = rootRef.collection("Marker PLaces");
```

Assuming you already have a "ListView" in your .XML file that looks like this:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/place_list"/>
```

Create a Place class:

```
class Place() {
    private String latitude, longitude, placeName;
    private Date timestamp;

    public Place() {}

    public Place(String latitude, String longitude, String placeName) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.placeName = placeName
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getPlaceName() {
        return placeName;
    }
}
```

Then define the adapter class:

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Place> {
    public PlacesAdapter(Context context, List<Place> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View listItemView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }

        Place place = getItem(position);

        String placeName = place.getPlaceName();
        ((TextView) listItemView).setText(placeName);

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Then in your `onCreate()` method use the following code:

```
List<Place> placeList = new ArrayList<>();
ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.place_list);
PlacesAdapter placesAdapter = new PlacesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), placeList);
mListView.setAdapter(placesAdapter);
```

And right after that, get the data and notify the adapter about the changes:

```
placesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Place place = document.toObject(Place.class);
                placeList.add(place);
            }
            placesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

The result of this code will be ListView full of place names.

Comment: How about if I want to make the Documents in Marker Place to an Auto Complete Text View? I want to implement a search bar on the top of the app so I need an Auto Complete Text View. Can you help me about this?

Comment: I think article [How to filter Firestore data cheaper?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) might help you achieve that.